# Python 2 and Python 3 common dist packages folder

Tags: shared-folders

I have a little issue with my Python dist packages.
Here is a brief explanation.

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, and have Python 2.7 and Python 3.4.0 installed on it.
Furthermore, I have "pip" also.

For my work (project) I needed to install some additional packages, like:"NetworkX" and "Pony ORM".

The problem arose when I installed "pip" and then PonyORM.

As I can understand, when I got the pip it was installed directly to `/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist_packages` folder.

This is because Python2.7 is a default version for Ubuntu?

I mean, for the case when I write `python get-pip.py` in the shell and not `python3 get-pip.py`.

So, my next decision was to install pip for Python3, in such a case it will (and it does) appear under: `/usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist_packages` folder.

Then I just installed "Pony ORM" one more time and now I have this package in both folders.

But when I decided to install NetworkX,it turned out that after installing pip for Python3, it works ONLY with Python3. So now, I have no idea how to overcome this issue,  and install NetworkX in both "dist_package" folders.

What are possible solutions for situation? How can I deferentiate between pip installation?

Using `python pip install something` or `python3 pip install something` yields nothing.

Or maybe just create some independent folder and then update PATHs of both Pythons? But how?

Anyway, I will appreciate any help.

Thanks a lot in advance.

P.S. Please don't blame for English skills, it's still "under development" ^_^

Comment: Python2 and Python3 should be treated as two seperate entities. If you want to use both, then install any third party libraries in both of them. Also consider having a look at Python Virtual Environments http://docs.python-guide.org/en/latest/dev/virtualenvs/

Comment: Thanks Carl,

That is what I actually did, after writing this thread. Just need to get used to it.

Answer (score 0):

There should be a `pip3` executable after installating `pip` into `python3` that you can use to install into the `python3` installation:

```
pip3 install something
```

I'm not 100% sure if that is the answer to your question, but maybe it helps.

Answer (score 0):

To avoid any confusion between different versions of Python you can use the pip module from each python install.

So for Python2:

```
python -m pip install something
```

And for Python3:

```
python3 -m pip install something
```

To make sure that `python` and `python3` point to the desired python version you can check using:

```
which python
which python3
```

If the versions don't match or you have another python installed on your system then you can always use:

```
<path to python executable> -m pip install something
```